# How to consume messages from Apache Camel JMS as Transacted Batch?

Tags: apache-camel, camel-jms

I know there is component sjms-batch which could perfectly solve my problem, but that component exist in **Camel 3.7**, and i need to use **Camel 3.8**. According to Camel documentation this component doesn't exist anymore after version 3.7. I couldn't find what is the reason for removing this component.

1. Does someone know why sjms-batch doesn't exist in newer versions?
2. And is there something similar that i could use with Camel 3.8?